# How can I log outgoing TCP traffic including the full path of URLs?

Tags: networking, logs, tcp, tcpdump, netstat

I use a program regularly on Linux that makes a TCP request when it starts up and updates a file with an access token before launching. I'd like to write a batch script that makes this request (using curl or something) and does a few other things before launching the program, but I'm having a problem logging the full path of the URL being requested by the program.

I know how to log outgoing TCP traffic with netstat (`netstat -vWcep --protocol=tcp`) and with tcpdump (`tcpdump -i wlan0 -P out -v -w logfile.pcap`). Both of these programs only log the host name of outgoing requests. For example, I know the request is to `s3-1.amazonaws.com`, but I need to know what comes after that. I may also need to know what kind of data is being posted.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try tcpdump with `-vvvX` ? (side note: there are no URLs in tcp, only address and port; urls are an application layer thing)

Comment: @guido yes. I realized in my sleep last night that I probably need a proxy.